# Letting users embed Google Slides/PowerPoint in my app, terms of use?

Tags: powerpoint, google-slides-api, google-slides

I have an app that lets users upload meeting resources into one single place and present the whole meeting with different tools as a single presentation.

I would like users to be able to embed their Google and PowerPoint slides as part of their meetings.

I know users can publish their slides and get an iframe code to embed it into their websites. I would like to include a way in my app where users do this and embed their slides with the code provided by Google and Microsoft.

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cembed-a-document-spreadsheet-or-presentation

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/embed-a-presentation-in-a-web-page-or-blog-19668a1d-2299-4af3-91e1-ae57af723a60

I wonder if making use of this in my app would fit into the terms of use or if I need to have some special agreement with Google and Microsoft?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Answering your doubt about Google, you should check the [Drive terms of service](https://www.google.com/drive/terms-of-service/archived/), especially the part that says:

> *`Your Conduct.` Don’t misuse Google Drive. **You may use Google Drive only as permitted by law, including applicable export and re-export control laws and regulations. You are responsible for your conduct and your content stored in Google Drive, and you must comply with our Program Policies.** We may review your conduct and content in Google Drive for compliance with the Terms and our Program Policies.*

So the correct answer would depend on your local laws, in that case I strongly advise you to visit a legal forum like [LawStackexchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/). Additionally you can check the [program policies](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/148505) to learn more.